# Workbox: invalidate cache only if network request works

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am trying to determine a workbox caching strategy where it uses the cache if available, and only uses the network if the cache has expired. However, if the cache is expired, and it cannot successfully make the network request, I want it to keep using the cache until it the network request succeeds. How can I achieve this with the various caching strategies that workbox has?

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /\/api\//,
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'users',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 24 * 60 * 60 // 1 day
      })
    ]
  })
)
```

In other words, I want to refresh the cache at most once a day, but only if the network request succeeds. Otherwise, keep using the cache. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This may be possible using a custom plugin, but I am not sure exactly https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins

Comment: Another way of formulating the question would be that if the cache expired you want to use the NetworkFirst strategy. I know that is no solution but maybe it helps to find an answer.